# Symbolication of Crash Log fails to Symbolicate any Framework Libraries

Tags: iphone, ios, crash-reports, symbolicate, symbolicatecrash

I'm trying to include some crash reports with a TSI incident, however I can only get the logs to be partially symbolicated. I have tried using the Organizer panel in Xcode 4.2 and using the Perl script from Terminal. In both cases my own classes are symbolicated without issues, but all framework classes are not symbolicated.

The crash report is [here](http://www.1ndivisible.com/dropbox/crashlog.zip).

Log Header:

```
Incident Identifier: 5786AB19-6931-49E0-994E-9629C6CFEF09
CrashReporter Key:   28fbb8362f47f2aa88788705deca962ea68fabe6
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Process:         MKOverlayBugHarness [2069]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/346EB22C-FA8C-46E9-AE67-F465EF97D944/MKOverlayBugHarness.app/MKOverlayBugHarness
Identifier:      MKOverlayBugHarness
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-11-25 17:43:17.567 +0000
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0.1 (9A405)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  7
```

Example from the beginning of the log:

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x333fc258 0x333eb000 + 70232
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35f8725c 0x35f7b000 + 49756
2   MapKit                          0x37d6d798 0x37d11000 + 378776
3   UIKit                           0x34f1d6cc 0x34f17000 + 26316
4   UIKit                           0x34f456da 0x34f17000 + 190170
5   MapKit                          0x37d64028 0x37d11000 + 340008
6   MapKit                          0x37d62d6c 0x37d11000 + 335212
7   MapKit                          0x37d62ec4 0x37d11000 + 335556
8   MapKit                          0x37d635f8 0x37d11000 + 337400
9   MKOverlayBugHarness             0x0009cf3c -[MKOverlayBugHarnessViewController addOverlays] (MKOverlayBugHarnessViewController.m:46)
10  MKOverlayBugHarness             0x0009cfbe -[MKOverlayBugHarnessViewController buttonDown:] (MKOverlayBugHarnessViewController.m:53)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x37abc42e 0x37aa9000 + 78894
12  UIKit                           0x34f359e4 0x34f17000 + 125412
```

Binary Images:

```
   0x9b000 -    0x9dfff +MKOverlayBugHarness armv7  <d4dcf05552a93323b96eff71ef6e7293> /var/mobile/Applications/346EB22C-FA8C-46E9-AE67-F465EF97D944/MKOverlayBugHarness.app/MKOverlayBugHarness
0x2fe9a000 - 0x2febbfff  dyld armv7  <be7c0b491a943054ad12eb5060f1da06> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30686000 - 0x30689fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <b18e0a845b1e317c8abcf6b5d06b29a0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x306f7000 - 0x306fdfff  MobileIcons armv7  <2f4c13053206306996726629b0b7eb01> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x30711000 - 0x3071dfff  CoreVideo armv7  <474c89eb09fe3464851a20d76052341b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x30927000 - 0x3098afff  IMCore armv7  <c235020b86123e95820f7323916023aa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x309b7000 - 0x30a00fff  AddressBook armv7  <0a858565acd03f28a1bc69a650b64a7b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x30a08000 - 0x30a4dfff  GeoServices armv7  <6c9eb6372f723a57852cfc9ed7b78e31> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x30bed000 - 0x30bf7fff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <b93ee3136d1c3d44b1e513a56bb0f86c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x30f9c000 - 0x30f9cfff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <85582e1094633fccb52b50ca13c5a5d0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x310fb000 - 0x31138fff  FTServices armv7  <fc9e7d223d3f33898603cfba115f5094> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x3113c000 - 0x3113dfff  DataMigration armv7  <d067b65a904a3f438b5d9e13b208b117> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x3123a000 - 0x3123bfff  CoreSurface armv7  <fcb6a869daef3a3abc4300c28b218e9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x3123c000 - 0x3123dfff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <9c8cee9652453241ac1fc99eab05c40a> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x3140b000 - 0x31413fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <f07cb8d6dadf36919bae8ef6e5ce1749> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x3163f000 - 0x31705fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <ebbb32df194b331e9b3dc14e40f46833> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x3177d000 - 0x317b4fff  Security armv7  <b89c9f6373f037f2a4801558f97b9a95> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x317ce000 - 0x317d2fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <0a36fb9d60a43479943bafb2f81313b1> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x317f4000 - 0x317f6fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <4ccf76f0e6cb3cd7b4e0087c2f284a1d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x31809000 - 0x3194efff  CoreGraphics armv7  <641fb6e558f239588a8bd05dbefff99a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x3199f000 - 0x319a2fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <414332f9a55238bab2cbec323e0fc8da> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x319f8000 - 0x31b76fff  Foundation armv7  <ce466f428d953caaac6641d186665809> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x31ba7000 - 0x31bf1fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <d8489a4ce77933abac52394c43ff5513> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x31bf2000 - 0x31bf2fff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <d21222aad8c93d6c9580f9bf47071946> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x31c06000 - 0x31c50fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <1f4cacb552533c948122cb180f4192b3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x31c5c000 - 0x31d2cfff  WebKit armv7  <74661b1bf4613aafb827bfe0134ed92b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x31e02000 - 0x31e25fff  PrintKit armv7  <279fb51deec3377ab9f820af2da4d915> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x31e50000 - 0x31e56fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <09f21c3e774c30b1aab1b56c2d6efbc3> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x31e57000 - 0x31e59fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <6ddb7cf8a93830628787a5b83eea0f1d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x31fee000 - 0x31feffff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <dbd1e77a4beb309d8f160d927d442467> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x32080000 - 0x32085fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <9072462f28af3665875b3ecaba002c00> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x322e1000 - 0x32a98fff  WebCore armv7  <7137e0ea008f3a3e8ae9e57f96d34d1d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x32a9e000 - 0x32aa8fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <28583efb9f1b38e7ae83c667b07dbd08> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x32b24000 - 0x32b31fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <a6414b0a5fd53df58c4f0b2f8878f81f> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x32d8f000 - 0x32dbbfff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <f0eca72c10c537fa89b17fd97e003faf> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x32dca000 - 0x32e74fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <9aabff01422f3cb8960f93d11d2b6de1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x32f38000 - 0x32f3ffff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <c0093954f6ee329aa6b4848215bcb8c0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x32f40000 - 0x32f43fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <3237bc9c109e3354bc4b38b957243f31> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x32f44000 - 0x32f5afff  EAP8021X armv7  <16801802d86e3c479f3034034192faed> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x32f72000 - 0x32f86fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <81eb1b3e08cf3d7196313307ad60649d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x32f87000 - 0x32f8dfff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <f5633749a1c83058a28cd7d0b488e19f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x33002000 - 0x33002fff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <342170169bf232a0888912f5ef97112d> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x33021000 - 0x33145fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <24ff2747b3973aecb9c37960eba5ff4d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x331b6000 - 0x331c1fff  AccountSettings armv7  <090bb6a4f97433089b5cabc6a40c619a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x331c2000 - 0x331fefff  AppSupport armv7  <de0c2fbb95f8383db43acfb44e9c66fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x33245000 - 0x33288fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <be9a231cfe6e3ae387abb444a098bce9> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x332b2000 - 0x333a2fff  QuartzCore armv7  <ff595b1a042933249466e92433e1af6f> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x333eb000 - 0x33401fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <afd3cb06e20336dca2e5a6e11d080504> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x3350a000 - 0x33561fff  CoreAudio armv7  <2e4975a2156e328585f2a478e80704fc> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x33c5c000 - 0x33c81fff  OpenCL armv7  <e1d5bfcdb59934b0923b9307c75e7457> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x33c82000 - 0x341c6fff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <cc2edb3645d2390dbca5471d35f1bf6e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x343bc000 - 0x343dffff  Bom armv7  <0e6087f75a81345ea81751197ccb712c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x343e1000 - 0x343f6fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <97d6ebbb53ae3e0480f51771c9665613> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x344fa000 - 0x34509fff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <c581bffc87013530b3c2d017142395e6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x3450a000 - 0x346c6fff  ImageIO armv7  <df300f66a317352e92354a8a48af3453> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x34742000 - 0x3478bfff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <ad15503487243836b7c296f3439ba0c1> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x347ec000 - 0x347edfff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <4bb9797771d037879bec814fe750d86d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x34b8a000 - 0x34b8efff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <ee734c0e964934a887a66d170270b114> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x34c05000 - 0x34c1efff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <ad22ea5ee99a358691f9820e62c85058> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x34c1f000 - 0x34c1ffff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <791bb8b832943b2392c0c35228f52e09> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x34c4e000 - 0x34c6dfff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <31a0ffbb18bf3a28b46fd286733e7d9f> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x34cbc000 - 0x34cc8fff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <ea460e3f1ac338a9885d5752864dbffb> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x34cc9000 - 0x34db7fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <6e858938edb93162ba8cf25702f08b16> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x34ee3000 - 0x34ee7fff  libcache.dylib armv7  <4511f0ec5b713636aaade7245a12553c> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x34f17000 - 0x353b0fff  UIKit armv7  <97b527cd6fba35c6bb39263e0f362223> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x353b1000 - 0x353edfff  IMFoundation armv7  <d93ec1a0f854355da1e4f8aca176e749> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Frameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x353ee000 - 0x353f7fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <bf8d7c30f11a393a8adf4c8277e65aa3> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x3554e000 - 0x35599fff  CoreLocation armv7  <e959d4dd596b31eeaa49c8c0156b1e12> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x35679000 - 0x35679fff  vecLib armv7  <106ef8294b0d3c2d89e9230527846227> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x3567a000 - 0x3593bfff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <5490a87fe5153771b9c67940292842ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x3593c000 - 0x3593dfff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <f1963e7ef64e39a58ec1e39ed7c74849> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x35984000 - 0x35985fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <b8612b4ce18535aaa94f4b75c730e090> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x3599d000 - 0x359a2fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <4d8b38f1cb603f0d8af78c56c485f05a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x359a3000 - 0x359d8fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <753be0ebdcb13b24b1a4adcdc94d6bd9> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x35d7f000 - 0x35d82fff  CoreTime armv7  <e2f02260f2a63359b9a0a47c69f59c9e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x35f7b000 - 0x36008fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <1707c3cf3c5b3045af4bed38ff8420a6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x36038000 - 0x36215fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <da4f78fd20fb3b42b1a8be4f383d9c12> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x36216000 - 0x3621afff  Marco armv7  <526949ce76323de09ee69812383c2953> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x3621b000 - 0x3629afff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <af4718fee01734748c42f2214ab6883d> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x363d0000 - 0x363d4fff  FTClientServices armv7  <8f823e791c9e37b4b47323bb0286e86c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x36496000 - 0x364b6fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <f37418b7e89137bba433677d61cd779d> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x364b7000 - 0x36564fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <78462273eb5b38d1a0873b02f0e35e23> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x36565000 - 0x36574fff  OpenGLES armv7  <6d1afb451f50310895ec59864739e781> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x366df000 - 0x36828fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <1bc960f75d633190a09b093209a9f0c5> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x368c4000 - 0x368d3fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <79f1564c1b23303eb3b7db67f9375228> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x36938000 - 0x3693bfff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <c3a5b1659eb0302eb205498ffacb09f1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x3693c000 - 0x3697cfff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <9440420d838a382caa175399d74a5044> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x3697d000 - 0x36993fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <fd046316dedc34dd81a6601ea3b1e8a6> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x36994000 - 0x369ddfff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <05711081dd883c58a844c5f9c251e8c9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x36a02000 - 0x36a02fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <69d8dab7388b33d38b30708fd6b6a340> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x36a7c000 - 0x36a8dfff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <7d49e385ee5d3e7eb08d06525abd6435> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x36a93000 - 0x36accfff  VideoToolbox armv7  <49f9f09f23f7396b94a29bb1280759fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x36afc000 - 0x36b0dfff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <6bc443b0f87e338698cac9e5a96e8f8f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x36c5d000 - 0x36d03fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <d785fe33cd263f5aba861ad919c66924> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x36d28000 - 0x36d2ffff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <6ca7dca9370132a2a592356bf9f2170b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x36d70000 - 0x36dc1fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <dc2061145c1a3307829d4f3bfc547c1a> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x36dc2000 - 0x36dcefff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <eef915ed9b2c3433b03fd9030957b945> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x36eaf000 - 0x36eb5fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <bfaf7fb16e5a3b2ea07c47b8b2f2b64e> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x36fb3000 - 0x3702cfff  ProofReader armv7  <09d057676f6837cd9e7a735444b67e77> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x37034000 - 0x3710bfff  CFNetwork armv7  <6fbc9f187eaa30009780e70288c9f289> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x37166000 - 0x37166fff  Accelerate armv7  <a62771c826753815a5cae96eaa60ffd7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x372cf000 - 0x372d3fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <c2e6bd6dafde3097b47bc255a8c871ef> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x372d4000 - 0x3730ffff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <753daf497ca736739a30126661a522f1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x37310000 - 0x37354fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <9a79a2d389ba35389a30782ed01c46dd> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x37355000 - 0x37359fff  IOSurface armv7  <0f003f50b18e3dbf87607d819e0ac6b9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x374ff000 - 0x3753cfff  IOKit armv7  <e5f727892ee034a4be04e6da608f413f> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x3754e000 - 0x375a4fff  GMM armv7  <5b18530ef2ab39fcb5f28da01beec3d1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x375b3000 - 0x375c9fff  DictionaryServices armv7  <5bbab664f97932a79a1566fda3a4383e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x375ca000 - 0x37625fff  StoreServices armv7  <1463a9f90fbd3d349544cf016e1ddd46> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x37633000 - 0x3763efff  GraphicsServices armv7  <4ec745ffb2e039faab4b39a30268f707> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x3764d000 - 0x3766afff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <1e36ab94661c372bab5a801d68c79353> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x3781d000 - 0x37833fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <defe319d1f4d3c1c8c4f18ebd96b396a> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x37853000 - 0x3789cfff  CoreMedia armv7  <d585cf4e0cfa34fa8beaa43b06a4bcd7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x378aa000 - 0x378b0fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <1e374857ac68370095ddbafe94f021a1> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x3791b000 - 0x379f5fff  vImage armv7  <42a5e58ff1b9350cad90de36bd3ceb09> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x379f8000 - 0x379fcfff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <cfd957904957310381369729bfd9b2b0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x37a02000 - 0x37a72fff  CoreImage armv7  <b1d0678497f43769840f173c0f9dce20> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x37aa1000 - 0x37aa8fff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <f769ce305c3033ee90e8c2ecc4846619> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x37aa9000 - 0x37bc0fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <de9eefc6109735369cfd8f3de9895da0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x37d11000 - 0x37d93fff  MapKit armv7  <1dd7d48dbbb6395ca77b97c2db4ae36e> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
0x37db6000 - 0x37e07fff  CoreText armv7  <23150093d39b393e9bc5f8230176df47> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Could you please post the binary image section of the crash report and also the header of the crash report? There is mandatory information shown in there to answer this.

Comment: Hi, that is better, but not all enough. As the header points out, the crash happened in thread 7. Please provide the complete report. If Xcode doesn't symbolicate it, that is most likely because you don't have the iOS 5.0.1 symbols on your computer. I tried one symbol on my machine, and it looks fine, so if you provide all, I can symbolicate it for you.

Comment: I've added a link to the crash report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the symbolicated report: http://db.tt/KvyurSDm

MapKit call symbolication failed, because the symbol failed returned no classnames or functions with the given addresses. Either the symbols are defect, or more likely the information is not exposed.

Comment: You may want to check out http://hockeyapp.net/, a service I am involved in. It provides catching crashes for beta and app store including server side symbolication, as well as other things. Just used that infrastructure for your report ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very much appreciated. I'll definitely take a look at your service.

Comment: @paranoidcoder please use the PLCrashReporter mailing list linked here: https://www.plcrashreporter.org/support Also provide them some more details on what you are doing to symbolicate and what the errors are that you get.